# Distinguish session and system items in Mac OS X keychain

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keychain, sskeychain

How can I query the Mac OS X keychain to retrieve only session items ?

When I try to get all items like this :

```
[SSKeychain accountsForService:nil];
```

A session item and a system item have exactly the same attributes for the keys : acct, cdat, class, crtr, labl, mdat, svce

How can y query the keychain to get only session items or distinguish them ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found by opening the user keychain :

```
NSArray *path = [NSHomeDirectory() pathComponents];
NSString *keychainPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@%@",path[0],path[1],path[2],@"/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"];
SecKeychainRef ref = NULL;
SecKeychainOpen([keychainPath UTF8String],&ref);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the session password like this (replace `kSecMatchLimitOne` with `kSecMatchLimitAll` if you need all passwords. The `attributes` will have `CFArrayRef` type in this case):

> ```
> NSDictionary* passwordQuery = @{
>     (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : sessionServiceName,
>     (__bridge id)kSecClass : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
>     (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
>     (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
>     (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit : (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne
> };
>
> CFTypeRef attributes = nil;
> OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)passwordQuery, &attributes);
> if (status != 0){
>     return nil;
>  }
> ```

Comment: I already have all items but I want only session items and not system items

Comment: Oh, ok. Then (probably) using valid `kSecAttrService` during item creation is the only way to find such items later. I've just checked on my system (OS X 10.8) and got a lot of different values for acct attributes (Safari, AirPort, etc.). So as an option you can create a list of "standard" services and then filter them out.

Comment: I have found, check my answer